# Yii login authentication. am facing this error

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have implemented my project in Yii. I done my login authentication its working fine another system. same project copied to one more system. the following error am facing

`session_regenerate_id()`: **Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent
how to clear this error**

Answer (score 0):

This problem can come because of config files  main.php.

Please check out below thing:-

Is there any blank space before starting of main php tag

```
config/main.php

 or

 Controller file of login

 or

 any custom file you have made
```

Comment: above answer could work. some one giving tip to solve this error. could you suggest me where to use this code